# How to retrieve certificates from the Local Computer\Personal\Certificates path in Groovy Jmeter

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

I'm trying to retrieve certificates stored in the "Local Computer\Personal\Certificates" path on my Windows machine using Groovy in JSR223 Sampler in Jmeter. I'm testing my code with the following snippet:

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.io.IOException;

try {
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
    keystore.load(null, null);
    
    String keystoreProvider = keystore.getProvider().getName(); 

    Enumeration<String> aliases = keystore.aliases();
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
        String alias = aliases.nextElement();
        Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);

        if (cert instanceof X509Certificate) {
            X509Certificate x509Cert = (X509Certificate) cert;

            log.info("Location: " + keystoreProvider);
            log.info("Alias: " + alias);
            log.info("Subject: " + x509Cert.getSubjectDN());
            log.info("Issuer: " + x509Cert.getIssuerDN());
            log.info("Serial Number: " + x509Cert.getSerialNumber());
            log.info("Valid From: " + x509Cert.getNotBefore());
            log.info("Valid To: " + x509Cert.getNotAfter());
            log.info("------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

However, this code retrieves various certificates, but it doesn't seem to retrieve the ones located in 'Personal\Certificates.' Could this be due to an issue with the KeyStore instance? What could be causing this discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Personal Certs or Local Certs aren't possible until later versions of Java.

https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6782021

Either JDK 17 or 19+.